# mvc dropdown not showing selected index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following on my controller:

```
string preferredLanguage = "fr-ca";
ViewData["Languages"] = new SelectList(languages, "Code", "Name", preferredLanguage);
```

On the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Languages", (SelectList)ViewData["Languages"], new { id = "Languages" });
```

My problem here is my dropdown is not setting the selected index of dropdown to the preferred language which is supposed to be French.

Note:

The values inside the `languages`:

```
1) Name = "English"
   Code = "en-us"

2) Name = "French"
   Code = "fr-ca"
```

And the dropdown shows two languages, English and French. English is set as selected index but what I want is French.

The reason I show the `languages` this way because this object are being retrieved from the database my a method and not by hardcoded. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using strongly-typed helpers bound to a model; something along these lines:

**Model:**

```
public class LanguageFormModel
{
    public string SelectedLanguage { get; set; }

    public SelectList Languages { get; set; }
}
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult YourActionName()
{
    // replace this with however you're getting your language variable
    var languages = new CollectionOfSomeSort();

    var model = new LanguageFormModel()
    {
        SelectedLanguage = "fr-ca",
        Languages = new SelectList(languages, "Code", "Name", "fr-ca")
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Your.Fully.Qualified.Namespace.LanguageFormModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLanguage)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguage, Model.Languages, "Select one...")
```

I'm personally not a huge fan of using `ViewData` for anything other than simple messages, and even then I use `TempData`, since I'm mostly just showing confirmations/alerts.

Comment: I already have a strongly type object on my view, it just doesn't include the list of languages, but only the language he wants. But this helped me solve my problem by doing the last line your view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me.

```
Dictionary<string, string> languages = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "en-us", "English" }, { "fr-ca", "French" } };
ViewData["Languages"] = new SelectList(languages, "key", "value", "fr-ca");
```

IN VIEW

```
@Html.DropDownList("Language", ViewData["Languages"] as SelectList, new { id = "Languages" })
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i'm currently using the first one. See update on my code. Thanks!

Comment: This is weird. I updated my code and we have the same now but mine is not working. Might missed something.

Answer (score 0):

this is ok:

```
@Html.DropDownList("languages")
```